# Not able to Save Data for Custom Customer Tab on Admin Side

Tags: magento2, customer, tabs

Have a custom tab extension on the admin side for a customer profile. It has a number of form fields that need to be saved but for some reason the values for the form is not coming across in the request object. I am using the `collective_customer_save_after` which is being triggered but again the values are not in the request object

```
$params = $this->_request->getParam('collective');
```

Below is the code for the tab and observer class (note I changed the namespaces for client anonymity). I do not have a controller, I am assuming I do not need one for the observer pattern.

> Tab Block

```
namespace Company\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
/**
* Customer account form block
 */
class Collective extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
 */
protected $_systemStore;
/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
     \Company\Extension\Model\CollectiveProfile $profile,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
    $this->_profile = $profile;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

public function getCollectiveProfile()
{
    if (!$this->_profile->getId()) {
        $this->_profile->load($this->getCustomerId(), 'customer_id');
    }
    return $this->_profile;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getCustomerId()
{
    return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getTabLabel()
{
    return __('collective');
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
 */
public function getTabTitle()
{
    return __('Hoop Collective');
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function canShowTab()
{
    if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isHidden()
{
   if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Tab class getter
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabClass()
{
    return '';
}

/**
 * Return URL link to Tab content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTabUrl()
{
    return '';
}

/**
 * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAjaxLoaded()
{
    return false;
}
public function _prepareForm()
{
    if (!$this->canShowTab()) {
        return $this;
    }
    /**@var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('collective_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('collective_form', ['legend' => __('Hoop Collective Information')]);
    $profile = $this->getCollectiveProfile();


    $fieldset->addField('company_name', 'text', array(
        'label' => __('Company Name'),
        'title' => __('Company Name'),
        'name' => 'collective[companyname]',
        'data-form-part' => $profile->getCompanyName(),
    ));

    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

}

> Observer Class

```
<?php

namespace Hoopologie\HoopCollective\Observer\Backend;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
    * Request
    *
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
    */
    protected $_request;

    /**
    * Manager
    *
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
    */
    protected $_messageManager;

    protected $_profile;

    /**
    * customer
    *
    * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory ,
    */

    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Hoopologie\HoopCollective\Model\CollectiveProfile $profile,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ){
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_profile = $profile;
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }
    /**
    *
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    * @return $this
    */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        if (!$customer->getId()) {
            $this->_messageManager->addError('no customer id');
        }
        $params = $this->_request->getParam('collective');

        // Update reward account settings
        $profile = $this->_profile->load($customer->getId(), 'customer_id');
        $this->_messageManager->addError('profile loaded');
        $this->_messageManager->addError($params['companyname'] . ' name');
        $profile->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        if (!$profile->getId() && !empty($params['companyname'])) {
        $profile->setCompanyName($params['companyname']);
        }else{
        $profile->setCompanyName($params['companyname']);
        $profile->setCustomerName($params['customername']);
        }

        try {
            $profile->save();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->_messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Answered my own question. I needed the data-form-part to be set to the 'target_form'.

```
'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
```

Comment: Brother, I owe you a beer. You don't know how much you helped me here.